# Pygame.movie black screen

Tags: python, pygame, mpeg

I try to read a video file with pygame.movie module but everytime i tried i got a black screen with no errors even the sound works. I'm using a mpeg file.
My version of python is 3.3.0x64 pygame 3.3x64.
I tried with python 2.7.1 x32 and 2.7 x32 pygame but same problem.

Here is an exemple of code that i used:

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080,720))
movie = pygame.movie.Movie("output.mpeg")
movie.play()
while True:
    if not(movie.get_busy()):
        print("rewind")
        movie.rewind()
        movie.play()
    if pygame.QUIT in [e.type for e in pygame.event.get()]:
        break
```

I really need to be able to play videos, i don't know how to do to solve this problem if someone knows the solution or has python setup that works with pygame.movie module please tell me

Comment: Are you running windows? Try using another video driver `import os` and then `os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'` *before* `import pygame`

Comment: I'm running on windows, i tried what you said still back screen

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out, my mpg file were not good, i tried some built converter but this is not correct you need to install ffmpeg and then convert your video file with this command : 
ffmpeg -i infile -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec libmp3lame -intra outfile.mpg

infile = nameofyourfile.format